# If I install Burp certificate in my system and try to access HSTS certified site and site will work and is it safe?

Tags: burp-suite, hsts

Can I intercept request via burp suite CA certificate for HSTS sites and is it safe or not?

Comment: It will work yes. You will have as much trust as you have in your own device. You will be intercepting and man in the middling your own traffic, so you will inherit any risks relating to that, which is purposefully breaking the standard trust model.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the fact whether you have installed the BurpSuite(portswigger) certificate as a trusted authority in the browser. Once you do that, you can intercept any website with burpsuite. But if you do not install the above mentioned certificate in your browser, you will not be able to intercept website which has HSTS enabled.
The website being safe or not is not related to whether the site can be intercepted or not using burpsuite.

Answer (score 0):

[HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)  is mean to enforce https connection and ensure certificate validity to prevent DNS hijacking attack.

It doesn't mitigate [TLS security attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Attacks_against_TLS.2FSSL).

Comment: How is HSTS meant to "ensure certificate validity to prevent DNS hijacking attack"?